# How to element content into new element

Tags: html, html-table, element

Is there a way to move content within a element into a another element

for example :

```
<td>move this content</td>
<div>into here</div>
```

Comment: You need to use Javascript

Comment: I have tried to use javascript but what I have done so far just wraps the td around a div. How do I use javascript to repace the tds with divs ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jquery for this:

```
$("#moveFrom").appendTo("#moveHere");
```

Refer [appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Tu7Nc/177/)**